# Closing InputStream contained in an object

Tags: java, io

What is the proper way to close an `InputStream` that is part of an object?

```
class Uploadable {
    InputStream is;
    ...
}
```

This object is passed on to an upload method:

```
uploadMethod(Uploadable up);
```

The way to create the Uploadable is either:

- From a `Part` object in a `Servlet`. There is a `part.getInputStream()` which returns an `InputStream`.
- From a `byte[]`, which is passed on by some Web Services. The `InputStream` can be obtained with a `new ByteArrayInputStream`.

The problem is once the `InputStream` is in the object, the ability to close it nicely is sort of lost, because the object is created in one place but used in other places. This limits my ability to use try-with-resources, because the object might not be used inside the context of the `try` block. The only way I see is to make `is` immutable and create a specific `Uploadable.close()` method that closes the `InputStream` whenever the use is done. Alternatively, I can store a `byte[]` instead of `InputStream` and convert the `part.getInputStream()` into an array of bytes. However, it seems a bad performance decision to me, since I will get an `InputStream`, convert it to `byte[]` to be latter converted again to `InputStream` in the upload method.

I suppose this is a very well known problem but I can't find best practices. Oracle always [closes the object](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glraq.html) in the try-with-resources block or the `finally` block.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you implement `AutoCloseable` yourself in the `Uploadable` and leave closing that to the creator/caller.

```
class Uploadable implements AutoCloseable {
    InputStream is;
    public void close() throws IOException {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        }
    }
}
```

This way, the `Uploadable` can be created in a try-with-resource block if needed, or not - in which case the responsibility of closing it is left to the client code.

Comment: That is what I said I cannot do... because the object is created in one place and is not used within the context of the try-with-resources block. Otherwise I would have no problem

Comment: @user1156544 Oh, I misunderstood. I thought you meant the creation of the `InputStream` itself. Then read the whole stream as it gets set into a `byte[]` and return a stream of that as required.